# HTML form not submitting input values with post/get method

Tags: php, html, forms, post, methods

This a section of my html form:

```
<form method ="post" action="switch.php">
    <p class="option">Favorite Book: <input type = "text" name = "book" id="book" size = "25" /> </p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

This is a section of my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['book'])){
    $person1book=$_POST['book'];
    $person2book=$_POST['book'];
}else{
    $person1book="Pride and Prejudice";
    $person2book="Crime and Punishment";
}
```

I basically have a form that needs to change a variable's value if the input is not left blank.

I've tried:

- The get method with no luck
- $_REQUEST with no luck

It just appears as if the input form is not submitting anything.

If you are seeing anything that I am missing, I would greatly appreciate the help!

*edit with more explanation:

On one page I have a form where the user has an option to choose a person and fill out their favorite book. Then I post it to switch.php where the variables change if the form input is filled out. Switch.php also redirects the page to another page that depends on which person the user picked that displays their favorite book. Each person has a default favorite book, but can be changed if the user fills out the form, except whenever I fill out the form it always displays the default value.

Comment: Is your PHP code in **switch.php**?

Comment: I check you form sent data, anything else that we should know?

Comment: You need to provide all the code from **switch.php**.  Why are you assigning the same values to $person1book and $person2book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why are my empty submissions not being replaced?

With empty values, the first condition (`isset`) will still be **true**. To prevent this, I'd put add the condition of `!empty($variable)` to `isset($_POST['book'])` so empty values will not stop there.

---

## How would I fix that?

```
if(isset($_POST['book']) && !empty($_POST['book'])){
    $person1book=$_POST['book'];
    $person2book=$_POST['book'];
}else{
    $person1book="Pride and Prejudice";
    $person2book="Crime and Punishment";
}
```

---

## They should also be redirected. How do we do that?

There are many ways of doing this, logically, but you use an `option` element to have users choose their person from the html page. You can store this site-wide through using PHP's `sessions`.

You can read more about PHP Sessions from [W3's PHP5 guide](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

PHP can redirect users using `header()`. In this case, we used `header('Location: /1')` and `header('Location: /2')`, depending on the person.

You can read more about PHP headers on the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

**index.html**

```
<form method ="post" action="switch.php">
    <p class="option">Favorite Book: <input type = "text" name = "book" id="book" size = "25"/></p>
    <select name="person" required>
        <option value="1">Select a person</option><!--Defaults to one if not specified.-->
        <option value="1">Person1</option>
        <option value="2">Person2</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

**switch.php**

```
<?php session_start();

if(isset($_POST['book']) && !empty($_POST['book'])){
    $person1book=$_POST['book'];
    $person2book=$_POST['book'];
}else{
    $person1book="Pride and Prejudice";
    $person2book="Crime and Punishment";
}

if ($_POST['person'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['person'] = $person1book;
    header('Location: /1');
} else if($_POST['person'] == 2) {
    $_SESSION['person'] = $person2book;
    header('Location: /2');
}
?>
```

**/1/index.php**

```
<?php session_start();

echo "<b>Person1</b> page with book: <b>" .$_SESSION['person']. "</b>.";
echo "<br/><hr/><b>Output:</b></br>" .$_SESSION['new'];


?>
```

**/2/index.php**

```
<?php session_start();

echo "<b>Person2</b> page with book: <b>" .$_SESSION['person']. "</b>.<br/>";
echo "<br/><hr/><b>Output:</b></br>" .$_SESSION['new'];


?>
```

---

## Solution

[image: Solution]

---

Initial answer:

```html
---

Before
===
[![Before Solution (broken)][1]][1]

---

After
===
[![After Solution (fixed)][2]][2]
    
---
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6NQS.gif
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGjEv.gif
```

Comment: Hey Cody, unfortunately still no luck. I have confirmed that the values are getting posted. I did a simple echo on the switch.php page and everything worked, it's got to be something with the if statement like you said. Note that only one book will display as there is a different results page for each person.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good here

```
<form method="POST" action="switch.php">
    <p class="option">Favorite Book: <input type = "text" name="book" id="book" size="25" /> </p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

If you are posting on same page remove action

```
if(empty($_POST['book'])) {
    $person1book = "Pride and Prejudice";
    $person2book = "Crime and Punishment";
}else{
    $person1book = $_POST['book'];
    $person2book = $_POST['book'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, am posting to a separate page though.

Comment: are you able to see page refresh on click?

Comment: Yes it redirects to the results page, but always displays the default value. The problem is whenever I fill out the form, the value never changes.

Comment: try printing all $_POST value you are getting on switch.php

Comment: echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; exit(); at the start of switch.php in php tags

Comment: I did an echo and it the inputted value was posted. It has to be something with the variable assign in the if statement.

Comment: @JonathanChristensen as demonstrated Cody Bennett his example is working fine as per your requirement. If your are looking for something else Please do tell me I will be happy to help you.